# Getting org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ioc

I am getting below dependency error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'BatchConfig' defined in file [C:\Official\Project\UserStory\git\governance-service\service\target\classes\governance\config\BatchConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'int' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I have Configuration class as below

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BatchConfig {

  @Value("${tps}")
   private int tps;

}
```

application.yml:

```
tps: 4
```

when I am removing variable tps application is starting correctly.
if tps is there its giving dependency error.

Can you help me with it

Comment: Well it does exactly what you told it to do. Create a constructor with that argument, however it will not place the `@Value` on top of it. Hence the error. Just write the constructor yourself or remove the `@AllArgsConstructor` so the default constructor will be used instead.